# Best practices when displaying a table within an ordered list

Tags: html, html-table, html-lists, standards, w3c

I am trying to figure out the best way to code the below page layout example which displays a full-width table within an ordered list. Normally, I could cheat and use two bulleted lists with a table between them but the requirement now is to use an ordered list and have the numbers continue while the table is still within the list items:
[image: page layout example showing a table within an ordered list.]

As you can see, everything below the H1 is indented with margin spacing except for the table, which is between the second and third list items.

**My main question:**
Since we cannot place ***DIV***s and ***TABLE***s between a ***OL*** and ***LI*** tag, what is the proper way to code this layout while also keeping proper HTML list layout standards?

My incorrect code:

```
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p></p>
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          ...
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Thank you!

Comment: A little confused, but is one thing you're trying to do is have the table the same width as the elements (with their `padding`/`margin`)?

Comment: No, sorry for those added details... the table is intentionally wider so that it can fit more content. The issue the placement of the table. I keep seeing w3c standards stating that you cannot place a table within a list. I need to be able to code the above layout somehow, correctly. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the first part of the list, put the table, start a new list with `start="3"` to resume numbering:

```css
.table-container table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-container table td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="table-container">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Baz</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <ol start="3">
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Clever! Thank you - I had overlooked the "start" attribute and it looks like it's available in all browsers... I'm hoping screen readers understand it well enough. I can't seem to find any easy issues here. THANK YOU again!